# Simple PHP SQL WHERE

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

My code looks :

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(kolicina_djeca) FROM rezervacije WHERE datum_od = '$datefrom'";


$res = mysqli_query($connection,'SELECT SUM(kolicina_djeca) FROM rezervacije WHERE datum_od = "$datefrom"');

var_dump($res);
if (FALSE === $res) die("Select sum failed: ". mysqli_error($connection));
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
$sum = $row[0];
var_dump($sum);
```

I get always results NULL , but in phpmyadmin when i run same SQL statement i get integer 13.

Here is what i'm running in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT SUM(kolicina_djeca) FROM rezervacije WHERE datum_od = "12-08-2018"
```

Comment: what data you are providing in variable "$datefrom"?

Comment: Here is var_dump string(10) "12-08-2018"

Comment: replace 4th line with this code and check output >>>

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

Comment: There isn't errors, it returns NULL

Comment: Query is unsecure, [prepare your statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your query as given below....

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(kolicina_djeca) as sum FROM rezervacije WHERE datum_od = '$datefrom'";
```

Also, you have to replace your `$row[0]` with `$row['sum']`

```
$sum = $row['sum'];
```

I hope this will fix your problem